# sre_constants.error using any python module installation method

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have been trying to install some python packages (python 2.7), but I run into the same error message, no matter if I try to install it via pip or some other method. I also tried different packages, all with the same result. Does anyone know how I can prevent that error from occurring?

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 151, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, loader, code, fname = _get_module_details(mod_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 101, in _get_module_details
    loader = get_loader(mod_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pkgutil.py", line 464, in get_loader
    return find_loader(fullname)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pkgutil.py", line 474, in find_loader
    for importer in iter_importers(fullname):
File "C:\Python27\lib\pkgutil.py", line 430, in iter_importers
    __import__(pkg)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 26, in       <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    __import__('pip._vendor.packaging.specifiers')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 275, in <module>
    class Specifier(_IndividualSpecifier):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 373, in Specifier
    r"^\s*" + _regex_str + r"\s*$", re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Comment: Which command have you executed?

Comment: python -m pip install pymssql and python setup.py install